# I want to print a game map, splitted into several A4 pages. What are the dimensions (in pxs) I should aim toward?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The image in question is here: https://steamuserimages-a.akamaihd.net/ugc/967599421465067988/8CE9657B63A06C6C7CCB15C4BF0C6EEFEFB0F131/

That's the map of Hollow Knight. I want to print it on several sheets of A4 paper on a home printer. How do I go about cutting it right? How much space should I leave for edges? How many pixels should be to keep inscriptions readable?

Would be great if you could help me with Photoshop specifically.

Comment: This isn't a Photoshop problem really, more of a print problem, and you don't need Photoshop to print stuff.  You can [use Adobe Reader to automatically print a large document onto several sheets of paper](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/print-posters-banners-acrobat-reader.html).  Try that.

Comment: Some printers (and I think Win10 itself) have a possibility to print (using Paint) to set Poster printing so the slicing is done automatically.

Comment: @BillyKerr that's actually looks exactly as what I need! However I downloaded Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and the print does not have that Tiling option: https://i.imgur.com/9iBWzoO.png Am I looking at the wrong program?

Comment: @deimos Hit the "Poster" button. Looks like there has been a redesign of the user interface since Adobe published that article.